# События потеря фокуса двух объектов

Tags: javascript

```
$("#formaddnews").click(function(){ 
    $("#formaddnewsmenu ").animate({opacity: "show"}, 500);
    if ($("#formaddnewsmenu").blur && $("#formaddnews").blur) {$("#formaddnewsmenu").animate({opacity: "hide"}, 500);};
    });
```

Помогите с фокусом!

Как мне сделать что бы при потери фокусом двух объектов один из них прятался

HTML код

```
<form>
<input id="formaddnews" class="formaddnews" placeholder="Добавить запись на стене" type="text">
<form>
</center>


</div>
<div id="formaddnewsmenu" style="">

<img src="images/camera_7603.png">
<img src="images/forward_1087.png">
<img src="images/volume2_2290.png">

<div align="center" id="form_add_news_menu_bottom">Опубликовать</div>
```

JS скрипт

```
   <script>
    $("#formaddnews").click(function(){ 
    $("#formaddnewsmenu ").animate({opacity: "show"}, 500);
    });

$("#formaddnewsmenu").focusout(function() {
  $("#formaddnewsmenu ").animate({opacity: "hide"}, 500);
})

  </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На **Jquery** с помощью `.focusout()` можно отследить потерю фокуса.

```js
$("#formaddnewsmenu").focusout(function() {
  $("#formaddnewsmenu ").animate({opacity: "hide"}, 500);
})
```

```css
.inputs {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 1em;
  }
  .inputs p {
    margin-top: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputs">
  <p>
    <input id="formaddnewsmenu" type="text">
  </p>
</div>
<div id="focus-count"></div>
```

Comment: Не работает $("#formaddnewsmenu").focusout(function() {
    $("#formaddnewsmenu ").animate({opacity: "hide"}, 500);
  })

Comment: @TomasRedl, исправил ответ, работает

Comment: Блин не работает, может потому что у меня не форма а тег DIV второй объект. Нужно что бы на теге DIV работало

Comment: Добавил ещё код

Comment: @TomasRedl, по умолчанию,  `div` не может быть в фокусе

Comment: А что тогда может?

Comment: @TomasRedl, теги `<input>`, `<textarea>` и `<a>`